# node.js NPM - NPM not starting local server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell, npm

So I created an app with create react app and I'm in the project folder. I haven't changed the files a bit after the react app was created by create-react-app.

but whenever I try to run `npm start` it does the following:

> Starting the development server...

> PS C:\Users\[app directory]> [I can start typing here]

the browser window opens, but it says, this site can't be reached, localhost refused to connect. the browser is saying right because the server died. I don't know I've tried everything. The exact same procedure works perfectly on my other machine. I suspect it is something with powershell. I've tried the exact things with powershell, cmd, git bash. node and npm seems to be working fine, but the terminal just doesn't stay when it starts the server and immediately goes back to the next line asking for my input.